# Finding a 2-Sylow subgroup of $\left(\mathbb Z^\times_{11} \times \mathbb Z^\times_{13} , \cdot \right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

so I'm trying to work through this problem:

How many elements does a 2-Sylolw subgroup of $\left(\mathbb Z^\times_{11} \times \mathbb Z^\times_{13} , \cdot \right)$ have (i.e. what is the order) and how many 2-Sylow subgroups there are in $\left(\mathbb Z^\times_{11} \times \mathbb Z^\times_{13} , \cdot \right)$ ?
Find at least one 2-sylow subgroup and list all of its elements. (just in case $\mathbb Z^\times_n$ denotes the set of all $k \in \mathbb N$ that are relatively prime to n)

Now i think i can answer some of it so here it goes:

so the order of $\mathbb Z^\times_{11} \times \mathbb Z^\times_{13}$ is (or not?) $\left|\mathbb Z^\times_{11} \times \mathbb Z^\times_{13}\right|$ =$\phi(11)\phi(13) = 10\cdot12=120=2^3\cdot15$. 
So if that is correct then i know they are of order $2^3=8$ and i also know that if $s$ is the total number of 2-Sylow subgroups then the following must hold: $s\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $s\mid15$. So from that i can say that $s \in \{1,3,5,15\}$.

Now that's as far as i can go. I don't know how to construct such subgroups i know that the elements of those subgroups must be of order that divides 8 that is of order 1,2,4 or 8, i know that there must be an element of order 2 (by Cauchy theorem i think). But i don't have an efficient way of finding those elements and i don't know how to specify exactly how many 2-Sylow subgroups there are other than saying it's either 1,3,5 or 15.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_{11}^\times \times \mathbb{Z}_{13}^\times$ is abelian, and all Sylow subgroups of a given order are conjugate, so there is exactly one Sylow 2-subgroup. It consists of all elements of order a power of two. Since $ord(a,b) = lcm(ord(a),ord(b))$, it is generated by $(-1,1)$ and $(1,x)$ for $x$ a square root of $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Comment: thank you very much for your response.However, I'm not sure i completely understand your answer. Can you please elaborete a little more? why is there only one sylow 2-subgroup if the group is abelian? and how does one quickly finds all elements that are of order power of two? and i also don't see how ord(a,b)=lcm(ord(a),ord(b)) tells me that it is generated by (−1,0) and (0,x)

Comment: If the group is abelian, then it acts trivially on itself by conjugation, so conjugate subgroups are equal. The $lcm$ formula tells you that it suffices to find elements of order a power of two in the factors of the product. The unique element of order two in $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is $-1$, and elements of order 4 are square roots of $-1$. No higher power of two is an order of an element of the factors since their orders are $10$ and $12$.

Comment: thank you again. I was suspecting it has something to do with action. I see it more clearly now. However there are still thing that are not clear to me.This might be a silly question, but Is -1 always the only element of order two even if i'm not working in $\mathbb Z^\times _{prime}$ ? And why is there not an element of order 8 again? does it have to do something with 2*4=8 because i have elements of order 4? I really have to revise modular arithmetic it seems

Comment: $(-1)^2 = 1$ holds in any ring. There is no element of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^\times$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^\times$ by Langrange's theorem since neither of them have order divisible by 8.

Comment: oh Lagrange's theorem! Thank you. But is it possible that i can find elements of order two other than -1 in some $\mathbb Z^\times _{not-prime}$ ?

Comment: Yes: in $\mathbb{Z}_8^\times$, all elements have order dividing 2.

Comment: thank you. All of this this really helped make the problem more clear. I suspect all that is left to do now is find elements of wanted order and put them together. One more question though if you don't mind. If the group would not be commutative (abelian) how would one figure out the number of sylow 2-subgroups then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78971/discussion-between-joshua-mundinger-and-shaa-maan).

Answer (score 1):

We have $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^\times \times \mathbb{Z}_{13}^\times \cong C_{10} \times C_{12}$, whose $2$-Sylow subgroup is $C_{2} \times C_{4}$.

Therefore, the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}^\times \times \mathbb{Z}_{13}^\times$ is $\langle g_{11}^5 \rangle \times \langle g_{13}^3 \rangle$, where $g_{p}$ is a primitive root mod $p$.

Note that $g_{11}^5$ has order $\frac{10}{5}=2$ and $g_{13}^3$ has order $\frac{12}{3}=4$, as needed.

We can take $g_{11}=2$ and $g_{13}=2$ and then the $2$-Sylow subgroup is $\langle 10 \rangle \times \langle 8 \rangle$.

Comment: $C_{n}$ denotes cyclic group of n elements?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand the notation. Can you please explain what you mean by $g^5_{11}$ and  $g^3_{13}$? in particular what does the 5 and the 3 in the exponent mean and where do they come from?

Comment: thank you very much now i understand.